# Prolog script not loaded properly

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to load my hw4.pl into swipl and it doesn't seem to be working. I tried

```
swipl -s hw4.pl
```

and in the prolog shell,

```
[hw4]. 
['hw4'].
consult('hw4.pl').
```

It would say "true", but I don't see the "complied" line.

And when I try to query:

```
?- user(@anna).
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: user/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

My hw4.pl:

```
assert(user(@anna)).
assert(user(@tom)).
assert(user(@jeremy)).
assert(user(@lawrence)).
```

Any idea why? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I get when I try to load your file:

```
ERROR: hw4.pl:1:13: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: hw4.pl:2:13: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: hw4.pl:3:13: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: hw4.pl:4:13: Syntax error: Operator expected
```

I'm pretty sure that `@` is not valid syntax.  Change your file to

```
assert(user(anna)).
assert(user(tom)).
assert(user(jeremy)).
assert(user(lawrence)).
```

And you should be fine.

Comment: If I actually want the '@' character can I do something like assert(user('@anna'))?

Comment: @Nevvea yes, if you enclose the atom name in single quotes it can contain arbitrary characters; if you want a single quote you can escape it with a backslash: `'atom with \' in it'`.